# Python extract date time from S3 Path

Tags: python, datetime

Good Day!

I have a S3 path in the below format :
s3://test-bucket/test/AUS/int1/DATA/table1/effective_at_year=2019/effective_at_month=12/ndh_effective_at_day=12/ndh_effective_at_hour=03/ndh_effective_at_minute=42/
I would like to extract the date/time from the above path and make it a string.
I have used the below code and achieved the desired output but I would like to know if there is any efficient method to what I have implemented.

```py
    pth=s3://test-bucket/test/AUS/int1/DATA/table1/effective_at_year=2019/effective_at_month=12/ndh_effective_at_day=12/ndh_effective_at_hour=03/ndh_effective_at_minute=42/
    pth1=pth.split("=")[1:]
    res = [int(sub.split('/')[0]) for sub in pth1]
     '-'.join(str(dt) for dt in res[:3])+' '+':'.join(str(dt) for dt in res[3:])
    output: '2019-12-12 3:42'
```

Your inouts will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample of how to parse and create a `datetime` object with the result:

```
import datetime

pth = "s3://test-bucket/test/AUS/int1/DATA/table1/effective_at_year=2019/effective_at_month=12/ndh_effective_at_day=12/ndh_effective_at_hour=03/ndh_effective_at_minute=42/"

# collect datetime components
# - assumes components are in the appropriate order
datetime_components = []
for field in pth.split('/'):
    if "=" in field:
        key, value = field.split("=")
        datetime_components.append((key, value))

result_datetime = datetime.datetime(*[int(v) for _, v in datetime_components])
```

`*` operator here unpacks the list providing the results as positional arguments to the `datetime.datetime()` constructor:

```
result_datetime = datetime.datetime(*[int(v) for _, v in datetime_components])

# is equivalent to

desired_components = [int(v) for _, v in datetime_components]
result_datetime = datetime.datetime(desired_components[0], desired_components[1], desired_components[2], desired_components[3], desired_components[4])
```

Once you have it in a `datetime` object you can easily manipulate it as you desire.

```
# 2019-12-12 3:42
result_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

> '2019-12-12 03:42'

Comment: Thank you. May I know what the * and _ does in the below statement: result_datetime = datetime.datetime(*[int(v) for _, v in datetime_components])

Comment: The `*` operator unpacks the content of the created list as positional arguments to `datetime.datetime()` here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know more details about AS3, only for datetime part, You can just use datetime.strptime.

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strptime('/test/AUS/int1/DATA/table1/effective_at_year=2019/effective_at_month=12/ndh_effective_at_day=12/ndh_effective_at_hour=03/ndh_effective_at_minute=42/',
                        '/test/AUS/int1/DATA/table1/effective_at_year=%Y/effective_at_month=%m/ndh_effective_at_day=%d/ndh_effective_at_hour=%H/ndh_effective_at_minute=%M/'))
```

Of course, you should remove the prefix first. For resolve URLs, you can use `urllib.parse.urlparse`

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
print(urlparse('s3://test-bucket/test/AUS/int1/DATA/table1/effective_at_year=2019/effective_at_month=12/ndh_effective_at_day=12/ndh_effective_at_hour=03/ndh_effective_at_minute=42/').path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `regex` to extract the dates:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

test_str = "s3://test-bucket/test/AUS/int1/DATA/table1/effective_at_year=2019/effective_at_month=12/ndh_effective_at_day=12/ndh_effective_at_hour=03/ndh_effective_at_minute=42/"

regex = r"=(\d+)\/"

values = [
  int(match.group(1))
  for match in re.finditer(regex, test_str)
]

date = datetime(*values)
formated_date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
print(formated_date)  # prints 2019-12-12 03:42
```